# How to insert a string containing ' through a variable C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using variables to store values onto table.

`f_nm` holds first name and `l_nm` holds last name of the person.

What if these strings for first name or last name contain a single quote ( ' )? I've been encountered to an error right now which indicates error near ' .

How do I write an insert query for inserting first name and last where

```
f_nm = Kevin
l_nm = O'Brien
```

Here is an example of the code causing the error (pasted from comment):

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( ' " + f_nm + " ' , ' " + l_nm " ' ) "
```

Comment: You should be using parameters, and then quotes and such is not a problem. Don't use string concatenation to build up SQL with both SQL statements and values, this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Why would an apostrophe be affecting you, unless you were using string concatenation to build your `INSERT` statement?  Can you post more code please?

Comment: INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( ' " + f_nm + " ' , ' " + l_nm " ' ) "

I'm executing it through a Windows Form Application.

Comment: Escape the ' in SQL. Two single quotes escape the single quote in SQL Server. Use parameters if inserting from C# code though.

Comment: See for instance https://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you would double the single quote:

```
insert into t (f_nm, l_nm)
    values ('Kevin', 'O''Brien');
```

However, if you are inserting values from an application, you should be using parameters.  Parameters would not have this problem.  So my advice is to use parameters.

Comment: No sir, I'm not directly inserting values. I'm accepting values through windows text boxes, assigning those values to variables f_nm & l_nm and then using those variables to information onto table.

Comment: Then you should use parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1